# Single or Multiple Models for Microservices - .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, microservices

So it's a migration of monolith app to Microservices where the standalone application will receive JSON files, analyze and return back some result without connecting to databases. So far I'm able to read and bind JSON with related models.

Since it's a migration, I'm referring to existing projects which has the core business logic. So the idea is to use the existing business logic & create a No Database Microservice where the data will be passed as Objects. Passing JSON to Microservice and then passing the same to the Business models is creating problem as some JSON fields doesn't match to Business Models fields.

I am thinking of the following.

1. Create the `FirstModel` to read JSON.
2. Map the `FirstModel` with the `BusinessModel` using `mapper` followed by assigning of non matching fields.
3. Use the Object of `BusinessModel` in the business logic.

Please do assist me if the above mentioned steps will suffice or if I am missing something.

**Objects has over 240 fields.**

```
{
"Obj": {
   "FirstName":"abc",
   "LastName":"def",
   "Age":"21",
   "City":"Auz"
}
}
```

FirstModel

```
public class FirstModel {
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public string Age  {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set;}
}

//Business Models
public class BusinessModel {
   public string First_Name {get;set;} //underscore 
   public string Second_Name {get;set;} //underscore
   public string Age  {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set;}

   [RequiredIf("City","Bangkok")]
   public int isCitizen {get;set} //extra field
}
```

Codes that I tried.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<FirstModel, BusinessModel>());
                var mapper = new Mapper(config);
                objBusinessModel = mapper.Map<BusinessModel>(objFirstModel);
objBusinessModel.First_Name = objFirstModel.FirstName;
objBusinessModel.Second_Name = objFirstModel.SecondName;
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. This looks to me like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking about how to solve the particular problem arised when trying to implement your solution, try explaining what is the problem that motivated this solution is, and then you go into what you're trying. In other words, please give us a bigger picture.

Comment: `microservices` is a fashion name. You have services. And services should be independent. What you call model is your API DTO only. It's not your resource, business or data model, just your DTO. If different services use different data they should have different DTOs. Maybe, just maybe, you could use the same DTOs if the fields are optional and the differences unimportant. That's a big maybe. Beyond that you don't provide any information beyond some mixed manual and automatic mapping code.  `a No Database Microservice` that means nothing. Almost all services store state with its own model

Comment: If that JSON comes from an external source, you have DTOs for that external source and those *can* be shared across multiple services.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Great, I got a new idea to use just One Model placing [JsonProperty("JsonFields")] on top of every fields where the fields are slightly different.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Really appreciate your helpful response. I will just use one Model. Thank you.